# Using synchronized to suspend active Thread

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm trying to suspend (or pause) the active thread using `wait()` I have implemented this in my code already but when I run the code it doesn't output anything, I think it's because when it runs it starts on "suspend"  would appreciate any help solving this issue. Here is the relevant code and a link with everything just in case.

**GreenhouseControls.java**

```
public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller implements Serializable {
    ...
    private Boolean suspend = false;
    ...

    public void SuspendEvent() {
        suspend = true;
    }

    public void ResumeEvent() {
        suspend = false;
    }

    public Boolean getSuspend() {
        return suspend;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Event.java**

```
public abstract class Event implements Runnable {
  ...
  private boolean suspend;
  ...

public synchronized void isSuspended() {
    suspend = greenhouseControls.getSuspend();
    notifyAll();
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      while (suspend = true) {
        try {
          synchronized(this) {
            wait();
          }
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      Thread.sleep(delayTime);
    }

    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      this.action();
    }

    catch (GreenhouseControls.ControllerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  
  ...
}
```

**FansOff.java**: there are other classes like this one each very similar to each other and they are the ones actually producing the output

```
public class FansOff extends Event {
   ...
   public void run() {
        try {
            boolean suspend = false;
            while (suspend = true) {
                try {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        wait();
                    }
                }

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Thread.sleep(delayTime);
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            this.action();
            System.out.println(this.toString());
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Full code: [here](https://repl.it/repls/LightcoralMonstrousKeyboard#Main.java).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you try to just post enough code to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: @Abra I just included the relevant Methods in the post, unfortunately, the assignment I'm working on requires us to implement the suspend/resume mechanism in GreenhouseControls making the information jump around a bit.

Comment: Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the section under the heading **Help others reproduce the problem**